# how to create simple bookmarker firefox addon

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I don't know why creating firefox addons is difficult. Maybe it's not my duty to create a new addons for company.

After 2 week in searching how to create firefox addons, I should say I don't know.

We need a simple addons for ***sending url of visited site to our server with a little information***.

It should have a form with some fields : **title**, **description** and a **selection area** with **submit button**.

When clicking submit it should send these information with url of this page to our server.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use page-mod - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod

You should insert a content script, which will port message back to your main.js telling it the information of that web page. Docs on port - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/using_port#port.emit%28%29

When your main.js receives that message, then you would use the request module to send it to your server. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/request

Now to get started follow this very simple guide to make your first addon - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Getting_Started_%28jpm%29

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I cannot understand, I started from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Walkthrough)

I created something, but I am not sure, can you check it. [Download](http://wikisend.com/download/186836/bookmarker.zip)

Comment: That's the webextension guide. It's not a complete API. I wouldn't recommend using it yet. Try the jpm guide i linked above (last link)